# gitlab checkout and status using Personal Access Tokens

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am writing a php application that will need to commit and check status of files on a gitlab repository.

my application asks the user to create the personal Access Token on gitlab [image: see attached pic]

All good so far.

I am using curl to run git commands and I am able to get the list of projects and branches on my project, but what I could not find is how to 'clone a repo' and check status on https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html.

How do I check out/get status using personal access tokens?

Comment: What do you mean by check status of files ? check if a specific file exists ?

Comment: i meant git status**

Comment: You shouldn't need the GitLab API to clone a repo,
also it's strange to use it for `git status`. Checking the status is something usually done for a local repo